# Test-Spy Implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

I have tried to write a test-spy myself. Just for getting more familar with the topic.

Here's the code:

```js
// --------- SPY - Start -----------------------------------
class Spy {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
    this.returnValue = null;
    this.result = null;
    this.countFuncCalled = 0;
  }

  invoke(...givenArgs) {
    this.receivedArgs = givenArgs;
    this.returnValue = this.func(...givenArgs);
    this.countFuncCalled++;
  }
}
// --------- SPY - End ------------------------------------

const calc = {
  add: (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  },
  sub: (a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  }
}

const addSpy = new Spy(calc.sub);

addSpy.invoke(9, 4);
console.log(`Used arguments: ${addSpy.receivedArgs.join(", ")}`);
console.log(`Return value: ${addSpy.returnValue}`);
console.log(`Count of function-calls: ${addSpy.countFuncCalled}`);

addSpy.invoke(8, 7);
console.log(`Used arguments: ${addSpy.receivedArgs.join(", ")}`);
console.log(`Return value: ${addSpy.returnValue}`);
console.log(`Count of function-calls: ${addSpy.countFuncCalled}`);
```

What do you think about my implementation? Is is done in a basically correct way?

I'm I using the ES6-features (Classes, Rest, Spread) right?

What would you have done differently and why?

Looking forward to reading your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think about my implementation? Is is done in a basically correct way?

Yeah who is to say what is "correct"? I mostly have worked with the [chaiJS](https://www.chaijs.com/) [spies API](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/) and it feels like a basic version of that library.

> I'm I using the ES6-features (Classes, Rest, Spread) right?

While there isn't much to the code, I would say it looks like those features are used correctly. You could consider using more class features like [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

---

In the constructor, there exists this line:

> ```
> this.result = null;
> ```

but the `result` property doesn't appear to be used anywhere. What is that for?